# does C# have something equivalent to Pythons random.choices()

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, probability-distribution

I'm trying to do choices based on their weight/probability

this is what I had in python:

```
import random

myChoiceList = ["Attack", "Heal", "Amplify", "Defense"]
myWeights = [70, 0, 15, 15] // % probability = 100% Ex. Attack has 70% of selection

print(random.choices(myChoicelist , weights = myWeights, k = 1))
```

I want to do the same thing in c#, how does one do that?
does C# have any methods similar to random.choices() all I know is random.Next()

*this python code works fine randome.choice takes in (sequence, weights, k)
sequence: values,
weights: A list were you can weigh the possibility for each value,
k: the length of the returned list,

I'm looking to do the same for C#,
choose values based on there probability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built into C# like this, however, it's not that hard to add an extension method to recreate the same basic behavior:

```cs
static class RandomUtils
{
    public static string Choice(this Random rnd, IEnumerable<string> choices, IEnumerable<int> weights)
    {
        var cumulativeWeight = new List<int>();
        int last = 0;
        foreach (var cur in weights)
        {
            last += cur;
            cumulativeWeight.Add(last);
        }
        int choice = rnd.Next(last);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var cur in choices)
        {
            if (choice < cumulativeWeight[i])
            {
                return cur;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in a similar way as the Python version:

```cs
string[] choices = { "Attack", "Heal", "Amplify", "Defense" };
int[] weights = { 70, 0, 15, 15 };

Random rnd = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(rnd.Choice(choices, weights));
```

Comment: Thanks man this is exactly what I needed, however the k value was missing and I just used a for loop with k amount to fix that. really appreciate this:) One other thing what are IEnumerable when used inside the method constrictor? I swapped it with a generic list just because that's easier for me, and works fine but what does IEnumerable do?

Comment: Glad that you modified it to your needs!  The IEnumerable interface lets you call it with anything that can be enumerated.  So, you could call it with a `List<int>`, or even a generator of some sort.  It makes the code a bit more flexible in how it can be called at the expense of some complexity.  And, as with such things, it's a choice if you want to have that complexity or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can get random.next(0,100), then choose the relevant item with a simple switch case or something. your domains will be like this , [0-70 , 70-85, 85-100]. let me know if you need full code.

```
    Random ran = new Random();
    int probability = ran.Next(0, 100);
    string s;
    if (probability == 0)
        s = "Heal";
    else if (probability <= 70)
        s = "Attack";
    else if (probability <= 85)
        s = "Amplify";
    else if (probability <= 100)
        s = "Defense";
```

Comment: yes 70 is a 70% chance of selecting Attack. If its not too much, yes a code would be nice. How it's done in python is so simple I don't know why there isn't anything similar in C#

Comment: Thanks man... @Anon Coward answered was what I was leaning towards, I upvoted nonetheless.